# Render component after useEffect modification React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I'm creating an app for TV and I need to create a QR Code with a value of a random code either fetched from localStorage or created on-the-fly if localStorage is null. The problem I'm facing is that the QR component is not being created on the first render (because "accessCode" is null), but after useEffect fills "accessCode", it still isn't being generated.
The code:

```
const Login = () => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(null);
  const [accessCode, setAccessCode] = useState(localStorage.getItem("access_code"));
  const [qrCode, setQRCode] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    let retrievedCode = localStorage.getItem("access_code");
    if (!retrievedCode) {
      retrievedCode = randomString(6, { special: false }).toUpperCase();
    }
    setAccessCode(retrievedCode);
    localStorage.setItem("access_code", retrievedCode);
  }, []);
return (
    <div className={styles.appMobileLogin}>
        {accessCode !== null ?? (
            <QRCode
            className={styles.qrContainer}
            value={accessCode}
            renderAs="svg"
            size={300}
            level="H"
        />)})
    </div>
}
```

I can't figure out how to re-render the component after the accessCode value has been updated.

Comment: Why not to initial the state with a random value ? 
const [accessCode, setAccessCode] = useState(randomString(6, { special: false }).toUpperCase());

Comment: I don't think the [?? nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) works like that.  Try `{accessCode !== null && (jsx)}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Nullish Coalescing Operator (??) is preventing the QRCode component to be rendered because the expression is not null/undefined when `acessCode` exists.

Change with `&&` instead.

```
{accessCode !== null && (
            <QRCode
            className={styles.qrContainer}
            value={accessCode}
            renderAs="svg"
            size={300}
            level="H"
/>)})
```

Explanation:

`??` operator will return "its right-hand side operand when its left-hand side operand is null or undefined, and otherwise returns its left-hand side operand".

In your case, when `accessCode` is different than `null`, the expression `accessCode !== null` is `false`, so `??` will return the left-hand side operand (false), so nothing will be displayed.

Comment: I've actually solved it in a different manner, but this would have been the proper way to solve it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Seems like working for me,

Please refer the below code sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-minsky-qr3n0f?file=/src/App.js

You may need to check how you are using the nullish operator change your operator to this

```
 {accessCode !== null ? (
            <QRCode
            className={styles.qrContainer}
            value={accessCode}
            renderAs="svg"
            size={300}
            level="H"
        />) : null})
```

or

```
 {accessCode !== null && (
            <QRCode
            className={styles.qrContainer}
            value={accessCode}
            renderAs="svg"
            size={300}
            level="H"
        />)})
```

for more on nullish coalescing operator refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator